# PowerBI - Average and Variance Calculation with conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate Variance and Average in PowerBI. I am running into Circular dependency errors.

This is my Data,

```
Month Year  Item  Count
1     2017  Chair  100
1     2017  Chair  200
1     2017  Chair  300
1     2017  Bench  110
1     2017  Bench  140
1     2017  Bench  150
2     2017  Chair  180
2     2017  Chair  190
2     2017  Chair  250 
2     2017  Bench  270
2     2017  Bench  370 
3     2017  Chair  120
3     2017  Chair  150  
3     2017  Bench  180
3     2017  Bench  190  
4     2017  Chair  200
4     2017  Chair  210
4     2017  Bench  220
4     2017  Bench  230
.
.
.
```

Average = Sum of Counts for the Previous 3 months / 3

Variance = (Average - Sum(CurrentMonth)) / Average

So, because the average won't be meaningful for the first 3 months, I wouldn't be worried about that.

Expected Output,

```
Month Year Item Sum(CurrentMonth) Average Variance
1
1
2
2
3
3
4    2017  Chair     410               497      0.21
4    2017  Bench     x                 y        z
```

> Lets Say for Chair,
>
> Sum of Current Month = 200 + 210 = 410
>
> Average of Last 3 Months = (100 + 200 + 300 + 180 + 190 + 250 + 120 + 150 )/ 3 = 1490 / 3 = 497
>
> Variance = (497 - 410) / 410 = 87 / 410 = 0.21

Kindly share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with this as Table1 (I added a couple months data to yours):

[image]

I loaded it into Power BI and added a column called "YearMonth" using this code: `YearMonth = Table1[Year]&FORMAT(Table1[Month],"00")` ...to get this:

[image]

Then I added another column called "Sum(CurrentMonth)" using this code: `Sum(CurrentMonth) = SUMX(FILTER(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Item]=EARLIER(Table1[Item])),VALUE(Table1[YearMonth])=VALUE(EARLIER(Table1[YearMonth]))),Table1[Count])` ...to get this:

[image]

Then I added another column called "Average" using this code: `Average = SUMX(FILTER(FILTER(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Item]=EARLIER(Table1[Item])),VALUE(Table1[YearMonth])<=VALUE(EARLIER(Table1[YearMonth]))-1),VALUE(Table1[YearMonth])>=VALUE(EARLIER(Table1[YearMonth]))-3),Table1[Count])/3` ...to get this:

[image]

Lastly, I added a column called "Variance" using this code: `Variance = (Table1[Average]-Table1[Sum(CurrentMonth)])/Table1[Sum(CurrentMonth)]` ...to get this:

[image]

I hope this helps you.